# ArrayLists in ServletContentListener

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I'm new with Jsp, and start some testing with Servlets and Listeners. 
My question is why I get a HTTP Status 404 - /DynamicExample/ListenTest.do when i start the ListenTest.do?

What I want to do is to declare multiple Dog Objects and put this in a ArrayList. When all the objects are stored into the ArrayList, then the "MyServletContextListener.java" whill set the attribute "dog". When that is done, will I send the attribute to my index.jsp page, but than get I a 404 file not fount.

ListenTester.java

```
package com.app.control;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.app.model.Dog;

public class ListenerTester extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Dog dog = (Dog) getServletContext().getAttribute("dog");
        RequestDispatcher forwardToLoginPage = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        forwardToLoginPage.forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

MyServletContextListener.java

```
package com.app.listener;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import com.app.model.Dog;

public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    ArrayList<Dog> allDogs;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) { 
        if (allDogs == null) { allDogs = new ArrayList<Dog>(); } 
        allDogs = (ArrayList<Dog>) event.getServletContext().getAttribute("dog");

        Dog d1 = new Dog("SomeThing");
        Dog d2 = new Dog("someThing");
        allDogs.add(d1);
        allDogs.add(d2);
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("dog", allDogs);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) { 
         // nothing to do here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your error page screenshot and your web.xml

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList<Dog>` can't be cast to `Dog`

---

You are setting it in `ServletContext` as shown below

```
allDogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
...
event.getServletContext().setAttribute("dog", allDogs);
```

Now you are retrieving it as shown below

```
Dog dog = (Dog) getServletContext().getAttribute("dog");//the problem is here
```

It should be

```
ArrayList<Dog> dogs = (ArrayList<Dog>) getServletContext().getAttribute("dog");
```

---

Do it in this way to avoid `NullPointerException`

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) { 
    //if (allDogs == null) { allDogs = new ArrayList<Dog>(); } //move this line below
    allDogs = (ArrayList<Dog>) event.getServletContext().getAttribute("dog");
    if (allDogs == null) { allDogs = new ArrayList<Dog>(); } 
    ...
}
```

---

No need to set the "dog" attribute in request because it is already added as session attribute.

Sample code for index.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList,com.x.y.z.Dog" %>
<%
    ArrayList<Dog> dogs = (ArrayList<Dog>) session.getAttribute("dog"); 
    for(Dog dog:dogs){
        out.println(dog.getName());
    }
%>
```

**Note:** use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm) instead of `Scriplets`.

Comment: Okey, now my 404 file not found error is gone, but when i will get the information out of this attribute in the index page it will be "null".      

<% String message = (String) request.getAttribute("dog"); %>
<%= message %>

Comment: because you are not setting in request attribute. you have just got in `doGet()` but doing nothing with it.

Comment: Please can you tell me. How many dogs you want to display in you jsp?

Comment: Later I want to insert many dogs, and will do it with an doPost() form. But now only two Objects without a doPost().

Comment: There was one more issue with your code that well result into `NullPointerException`. I have updated it in my post.

Comment: OK, but now i got a 500 error on index.jsp.

HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 13

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 13

10:     <body>
11:        <%
12:     ArrayList<Dog> dogs = (ArrayList<Dog>) session.getAttribute("dog"); 
13:     for(Dog dog:dogs){
14:         out.println(dog.getBreed());
15:     }
16: %>

Comment: use either fully qualified class names for ArrayList and Dog or use JSP import directive.

Comment: When i used that example, i got the same 500 error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 12

Comment: Do you know where the exceptions are logged?

Comment: No, I can't find those annywhere

Comment: Sorry I can't help any more. Try to find it out on Google or readmy my post again.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help so. But did you now any tutorial or example where she do what I want of something what lookslike this?